# Bekkeriana greek Typeface for LaTex

Tags: fonts, greek

Anyone knows how to use "Bekkeriana" greek typeface?

Comment: Do you have that font in your computer? If yes, you can use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Hmmm.  Someone knows, because there’s an example, sans source, at https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/ — possibly the work of Yannis Haralambous (mentioned in connection with this font at http://www.opoudjis.net/unicode/other_ligatures.html)?

Comment: No, I don't have that font in my computer, @JouleV

Comment: @LucianoGarófalo Googling it gives me nothing. Therefore I don't have the font, and I don't know if the font is contained in a LaTeX package or not. The best option for you is to find the `.otf` or `.ttf` file of the font somewhere and use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The site http://www.polytoniko.org/fonts.php says, before the sample of Bekkeriana, "These fonts are used only for the typing of Atelier Fluxus Virus, and are not available to the public. The names we give rise to the tradition of Greek typography; in brackets we also give the name of the corresponding font of the monotype machines."

Comment: You may want to look at https://www.greekfontsociety-gfs.gr/typefaces for other Greek typefaces.